# BOOST Preprocessor BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE nested loops

Tags: c++, templates, boost-preprocessor, explicit-instantiation

I have a templated C++ function:

`template<int i, int j> void foo();`

I would like to define it in a `.cpp` file and instantiate it explicitely. The parameters `i` and `j` have the same admissible range of values, from 1 to `N` included. So far, for a function with a single template parameter such as

`template<int i> void foo();`

I've been using the Boost Preprocessor library like so:

```
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)\
template void foo<n>();
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (1,N)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

This macro expands to `N` lines with `n` spanning 1 to `N`, each instantiating the function for the current value of `n`.

Is it possible to implement a nested loop using this library? Is it even theoretically possible given how the C preprocessor works?

I have searched for answers on stackoverflow with no success. Question [Generate nested for loops using C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73010922/generate-nested-for-loops-using-c-preprocessor) is similar to mine but (unlike the author), I would prefer to use the BOOST_PP lib if possible. My attempts to modify the above macro have been clueless to the point I don't think they are significant.

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to do this in one go with BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE, do it in two with a combination of BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE and BOOST_PP_ITERATE. Use BOOST_PP_ITERATE to do the outer loop and BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE for the inner.

Comment: You were correct, I'll expand your comment into an answer as this has solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to give you the right direction. It's been long enough since I actually used boost's preprocessor iteration that I wasn't at all comfortable trying to throw together a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

Following @SoronelHaetir's comment, I have implemented the following.

In a file `foo_instantiate.ixx`:

```
#if !BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING
   #ifndef FILE_H_
   #define FILE_H_
   #include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>
   #define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (3, (1, MAXITER, "foo_instantiate.ixx"))
   #include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()
   #endif
#else
   #include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>
   #define INSTANTIATE(z,n,t) template void foo<1+n,BOOST_PP_ITERATION(),0>();
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(0, MAXITER, INSTANTIATE, )
   #undef INSTANTIATE
#endif
```

This is implements a kind of file recursion. PP #includes the file specified as string (here itself) in the range defined by `BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1` (inclusive). Now, in each of these inclusions, macros will again be expanded. This allows us to use standard BOOST_PP iterative macros, here `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO`. The current file inclusion iteration is obtained through `BOOST_PP_ITERATION()`. So this effectively works as a nested loop. Note that `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO` excludes the last index.

I have called this file so in order to differentiate it from header files and to avoid issues with globbing for .cxx files in CMake. In the appropriate cxx file (say `foo.cxx`), I simply `#include <foo_instantiate.ixx>`. As a side note, CMake automatically generates a target `foo.cxx.i` (preprocessor output) which greatly helps in debugging these macros.